# Data store for capturing votes & aggregating them

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I'm interested in using Node.js as a socket server for stream-based communication with tens of thousands of clients. Clients will be sending votes for particular pieces of content and receiving near-real-time updates of aggregated vote tallies from the server.

The datastore needs to support:

1. Storing the votes
2. Summarising the votes in near-realtime
3. Preventing multiple votes within an arbitrary time period (e.g. clients can only vote once for a piece of content every 1 minute)

Something that already has client libraries for Node.js would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis). It is a key/value store with set and list operations. It also supports atomic operations for counters. There is a client for Redis for Node.js available on [github](http://github.com/fictorial/redis-node-client). Here is how I would implement your features:

#### Storing the votes

```
INCR votes:option:<option>
```

#### Summarizing the votes

```
MGET votes:option:<option1> votes:option:<option2> ... votes:option:<optionN>
```

#### Preventing multiple votes (create an expiring lock key for client IP)

```
EXPIRE lock:<encoded ip> 60
```

Comment: +1 for using redis, other alternatives would be here: [Database Modules for Node.js](http://wiki.github.com/ry/node/modules#database)